# Update Spyder Dependencies

Tags: python, python-3.x, spyder

I was previously using Spyder with Python 2.7, but just made the switch to Spyder3 which currently uses Python 3.4. My problem is that all the optional dependencies, which were previously installed and integrated in Spyder for 2.7, are now (NOK). In other words, Spyder3 doesn't have access to the dependencies I previously installed.

Is there a way to update Spyder3 to get all these dependencies without having to delete and download them again? Do I have to find all the paths for all these dependencies?

Here is what I get when I click on the Dependencies button in help:

```
#IPython >=1.0   :  None (OK)
#jedi >=0.8.1    :  None (NOK)
#matplotlib >=1.0:  None (NOK)
#pandas >=0.13.1 :  None (NOK)
#pep8 >=0.6      :  None (NOK)
#psutil >=0.3    :  None (NOK)
#pyflakes >=0.6.0:  0.8.1 (OK)
#pygments >=1.6  :  None (NOK)
#pylint >=0.25   :  1.1.0 (OK)
#rope >=0.9.2    :  None (NOK)
#sphinx >=0.6.6  :  None (NOK)
#zmq >=2.1.11    :  None (NOK)
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Spyder on Python 3.4 will need dependencies from your Python 3.4 installation. So it correctly indicates that you need to install these modules on Python 3.4 too.

Comment: Ah, that makes a lot of sens! Thank you, it works now.

Comment: Is there a way to use to store the list above as `requirements.txt` and then install it via `pip install -r requirements.txt`? Is there a risk of breaking something?